# how to compare of two columns in two dataframe( one contains another)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two df1 and df2

df1 is following

```
x1    x11 ........
----------
test1
test2
test3
...
```

df2 is following

```
x2          x21..............
----------------------------
test3_off
test2_off
test5_off
cat
dog
apple_off
....
```

the result im looking for is following

```
x3
-----
test1
```

basically, I want to find that cells are not in df_test2

test2 in df1 and test2_off df2 are considered same, so it should be filtered out.

I tried with `df1[x1].isin(df2[x2])`, this only compares exact string in cells.

so how could i achieve this with pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Is the suffix always separated by `_`?

Comment: it should be, but not guaranteed

Comment: By dataframes you mean two columns, i.e. two pd.Series?

Comment: there are more columns in two dataframes, but only one column in each is considered, i will modify question again

Comment: Do you have any information about the entries in `x2`? Are there always some kind of seperators (e.g. `-,.:;/_`) or ist it always a certain length (test1 has 5 letters) or anything that can be used in order to extract the matching part from `x2`? Or does it always end with `off` and has no other differences?

Comment: there are just some strings, could be anything in x2, my goal is to find a string from x1 if it's contained in x2 and filter it out.

Comment: I got that, but you always typed `test1_off` etc. so if the string is in `x1` does it have any sort of identifier? The other ones do not matter

Comment: hmm, x1 has no other identifiers, random strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 steps. Process your `df2['x2']` first, then select items from `df1['x1']` that is not in the processed `df2['x2']`:

```
# Recreating your datasets

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[f'test{i}' for i in range(1,4,1)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2':['test3_off',
                          'test2_off',
                          'test5_off',
                          'cat',
                          'dog',
                          'apple_off'
                         ]})

# Keep the term before '_'
x2_items = df2['x2'].apply(lambda x:x.split('_')[0])
```

Then, do your selection to get `df3`

```
df3 = df1[~df1['x1'].isin(x2_items)].rename(columns={'x1':'x3'})
```

and you get:

```
      x3
0  test1
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works:

```
[l  for l in  df1['x1'] if l not in  [x for x in df1['x1'] for j in df2['x2'] if x in j ] ]
```

This will do and you will get in list form, then you can convert it into dataframe

Comment: i believe x in j only compare full string? so this won't work i guess

Comment: try this one x in j compares partial strings also

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.slice if you know that Y starts with X, say, like this:

```
from functools import lru_cache

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'], 'x2': ['test1_1', 'test1_2', 'test2_1', 'test5']})

@lru_cache(maxsize=128)
def slicer(col_idx, length):
    return set(df1.iloc[:, col_idx].str.slice(stop=length))

mask = df1['x1'].apply(lambda x: x in slicer(1, len(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I hoped for a solution without the apply function, but without any information on the data in `x1` and `x2` except, that one contains the other I don't think that this is possible. So here the solution with the apply function. This way it doesn't matter, if it starts with the searched for string or ends with it or it is delimited by `'_'`:

```
df3 = df1['x1'].apply(lambda x: x if df2['x2'].str.contains(x).any() else np.nan ).dropna()
```

Test:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x1':[f'test{i}' for i in range(5)]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x2':['test3_off',
                          'test2_off',
                          'test2_off', # added for dup test
                          'test5_off',
                          'cat',
                          'dog',
                          'apple_off'
                          'abctest1def', #added for test
                         ]})

df3 = df1['x1'].apply(lambda x: x if df2['x2'].str.contains(x).any() else np.nan ).dropna()
print(df3)
```

Output:

```
1    test1
2    test2
3    test3
Name: x1, dtype: object
```

So duplicates are removed, the order of `x1` is kept and any matching string is returned.